# Is it ok to create Indexes on a database table from SSMS when the database is created using Entity Framework with a code-first approach

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, database-indexes

I have created my database from scratch with a code-first approach of Entity Framework. Any update I do in the structure I do it using code-first.

But now, I want to manage indexes on my database. As in create new indexes on some tables and drop the already present ones. Can I do it directly on the database using SQL statements in SSMS or I HAVE TO do it through code-first (changing code in the models) only?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index in SSMS, but if you ever have changes to your models you'll have to re-apply your indexes after running your migration.

In order to prevent this, you can modify the generated migration, adding a `Sql("add SQL code to add your index here")` call to the Up method.

As a matter of preference, you may also want to generate a blank migration, then add the indexing to the blank one instead.

Ideally, you should also add a corresponding `Sql()` call to drop the index in the Down method.